# Ubuntu+Gnome3 screen not dimming

Tags: unity, gnome, screen, power-management, brightness

I have an Ubuntu installation with Unity and Gnome3.

When I log in using **Unity**, if the system is inactive for X minutes, the screen will dim.

When using **Gnome3** the screen never dims.

Under **Brightness & Lock** I selected

- *Turn screen off when inative for* -> 5 minutes
- *Lock* -> is not activated.

Under **Power** I selected

- *Suspend when inactive for* -> Don't suspend